# Union results when looping a mysql select query

Tags: mysql, loops, union, repeat

I'd like to return a single dataset from a procedure that loops a select statement. In my particular case I am trying to get the values per row per date between two dates.

```
SET @end = DATE(NOW());
SET @start = DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -3 MONTH);
SET @today = @start;

REPEAT
    SELECT a, (SELECT latest b value on @today) as b FROM table;
    @today = DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL +1 DAY);
UNTIL @today => @end END REPEAT;
```

When wrapped in a proc and called I get a seperate dataset returned per loop. I'd like a single dataset with all results 'UNIONed'.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just....

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` t
WHERE t.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -3 MONTH) AND NOW()
ORDER BY t.date;
```

Comment: A new row is not created / logged every day (I have a nested select query that will get the latest value on a date). I need to be able to step through each day and take a snapshot (getting the latest row if not existing today) and then stitch the results together.

Comment: I don't understand -can you update the question with an example?